# How can I get windshield wiper fluid stains out of my garage floor?

Tags: concrete, cleaning, garage

My car's windshield wiper fluid reservoir had a leak and quite a bit of it soaked into my garage floor (which is a light concrete).  It happened over night, so it soaked quite a bit. Now the floor is stained blue!

I've tried using this concrete cleaner from Home Depot combined with veracious scrubbing with a hard bristle brush but to no avail:

[image]

[Link to cleaner](http://www.homedepot.com/buy/zep-128-oz-driveway-concrete-and-masonry-cleaner-zucon128.html#.UEf0BdZlSt0)

I also tried bleach and pressure washing.  Still blue.

Anyone know how to get windshield wiper fluid stains off a garage floor?

Comment: I take it the concrete hadn't been sealed?

Comment: You need some windshield wiper wiper fluid.

Comment: I don't believe the concrete has been sealed.  I didn't seal it, the previous owner might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have access to a steam cleaner you can try using the steam cleaner over the stained area for a few minutes to see if it will push the stain. If the stain is stubborn, you can try using your pressure washer after steam cleaning it and/or scrub the concrete. Let it dry and rinse and repeat, if it's still there.

Like The Evil Greebo asked, if the concrete isn't sealed, then the stain could be a bit difficult to remove or even permanent.

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is super old but my boyfriend and I had this issue recently. We used a little laundry detergent and comet at first. That helped a little but what really worked was kaboom, the one that's for the rest rooms. This really penetrated the concrete. We let it sit about 15 minutes and pressure washed it. We did that about 3 times and it did the trick.

Comment: Have you tried Simple Green?

Answer (score 1):

If that spot of floor is exposed to the sunlight when the door is open the sun will bleach it out over time. You could also try putting something on it to soak the color up like comet clensing powder,rice hull ash, or cement. Let it set for a week or two.  If it never comes out you could paint your garage floor with epoxy paint and never have to worry about stains again. I did mine in grey with flakes about 7 years ago and it still looks great.

Answer (score 0):

You could try an oxygen bleach like [Stain Solver](http://www.stainsolver.com).